# InfoPath Form Not enabled on all site collections

Tags: infopath, administration

hi i have two site collections

site a
site b

site a was created after the initial configuration of info path service

info path designer works great with site b  but when i use it with site a. it tells me that info path services are not enabled i have been looking for site collection specific configuration. but found none.

both sites are running in the same web application and are both top level site collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to restart the hidden InfoPath feature?

```
Disable-SPFeature "IPFSSiteFeatures" -url "http://webapp" 
Enable-SPFeature "IPFSSiteFeatures" -url "http://webapp"
```

Comment: thanks i was trying to find this feature :) didnt know what it was called lol

Answer (score 1):

Ensure this feature is enabled at the site collection level: "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features"